# Url delimiter with "-" MVC Routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a problem with MVC Routes.
I've used the route like this:

```
  [Route("{selected}/{category}/{id}/{engineId}")]
  public ActionResult SubCategories(string selected, int id, string category, string engineId)
    {...}
```

and the url looks like this: http://localhost:50564/Audi-60-1.5/Suspensie/76/43423

But now, I need to delimit the url parameters with "-". Can I do that? I don't have too much experience with MVC routes and I don't know how to do that. 
If I change the route to be like this:

```
[Route("{selected}-{category}-{id}-{engineId}")]
public ActionResult SubCategories(string selected, int id, string category, string engineId)
{...}
```

I have all type of trouble, for example the Session in the whole application became null, and I get null reference exceptions. With the "/" delimiter I don't have this problem, everything works fine.
  [image]

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic answer and only includes controller and action but has been tested and works. From testing also you cannot include - for the optional paramaters at best you can use a . You would also have to consider when you startup the application is the default route read correctly

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}-{action=Index}");
        });
```

Here is the error message when using - for optional parameter

```
RoutePatternException: In the segment '{controller=Redaction}-{action=Index}-{id?}', the optional parameter 'id' is preceded by an invalid segment '-'. Only a period (.) can precede an optional parameter.
```

Here is a sample url

```
https://localhost:44365/Home-Index.DocumentId=1
```

Comment: take a look at slugifer https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETCore22ParameterTransformersForCleanURLGenerationAndSlugsInRazorPagesOrMVC.aspx